# phonegap javascript ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I am a nnewbie in appdevelopment and tried developing a mobile app using phonegap. I have a remote shared server which consist the mysql table. I want to signup a user which will eventually send the data via javascript and ajax to a php sever page that will post the data on the mysql table.

but on my app the javascript codes in the header are not working. so is the js page in which i have the ajax coding to connect to the server.

what should be done?

```js
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    $(function(){
        $('signup').submit(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    alert("this");
    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                //change the url for your project
                url: 'http://205.251.133.242:2082//home/lyfspl62/public_html/addUsermobile.php',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                }
            });
            
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
     <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/post.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function sunc() {  
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    alert("loading");
    document.getElementById("home").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("login").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("signup").style.display="none";
   }
   function login() {
    document.getElementById("home").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("login").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("signup").style.display="none";
   }
   
   function signup() {
    document.getElementById("home").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("login").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("signup").style.display="block";
   }
   
   function validatel(){
    var emaill = document.getElementById("emaill");
    var pwd = document.getElementById("passwordl");
    
    if(emaill=="null" || emaill==""){
     alert("email must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
    else(pwd=="null" || pwd==""){
     alert("password must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
   }
   function validates(){
    var emaill = document.getElementById("emaill");
    var pwd = document.getElementById("passwordl");
    
    if(emaill=="null" || emaill==""){
     alert("email must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
    else(pwd=="null" || pwd==""){
     alert("password must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
   }
  </script>
  
        <title>LyfSplash</title>
  
  
    </head>
    <body onload="sunc()">
 
  <h1>LyfSplash</h1>
  
  <div ata-role="page" class="home" id="home" >
  
   <button type="button" onclick="login())" >Login</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="signup()">signup</button>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   alert("working");
   </script>
  </div>
  
  <div class="login" id="login" >
  <form >
   email:<br>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="emaill" autocomplete="on">
   <br>
   Password:<br>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordl" >
   
   
  </form>
  </div>

  <div class="signup" id="signup" >
  <form id="ff" action="http://205.251.133.242:2082//home/lyfspl62/public_html/addUsermobile.php">
   FirstName:<br>
   <input type="text" id="firstName">
   <br>
   LastName:<br>
   <input type="text" id="lastName">
   <br>
   Country:<br>
   <input type="text" id="Country">
   <br>
   City:<br>
   <input type="text" id="city">
   <br>
   Phone<br>
   <input type="text" id="phone">
   <br>
   Mobile<br>
   <input type="text" id="mobile">
   <br>
   email:<br>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="emails">
   <br>
   DOB<br>
   <input type="text" id="DOB">
   <br>
   
   <button type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  </div>


    </body>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your URL:
url: 'http://205.251.133.242:2082 > "//" < home/lyfspl62/public_html/addUsermobile.php'

Comment: any error are you getting?

Comment: no i dont get any errors but the javascript code is not working. i have written alerts to check it as well and none of them works. only the alert in the body works

Comment: try putting semicolon after your functions... so at the end };   sometimes it will chain them together if not.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the submit event handler to the wrong element. You should bind it to the `form` instead of the wrapper `div`. There's also the `#` missing in the selector. Change your code to this:

```
$('#ff').submit(function () {
    // ...
});
```

You are also missing the `data` in the error callback:

```
error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert('There was an error adding your comment');
}
```